# Localhost doesn't find other routes

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, php, ubuntu-gnome

I'm new on Linux systems and I have moved into it because they work better than Windows for web development.

I have Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS and I've installed PHP, Apache and MySQL using this command:

`sudo apt-get install apache2 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server`

After that, I put `http://localhost` and I see the Apache 2, Default Page.

Into `/var/www` I created a new folder for my tests and if I try to access from the browser I get the message

`The requested URL /tests was not found on this server`

I don't know how I can get access to my other folders, I tried to search it in Google but I see that the result for the localhost URL is a page showing `It works!`

EDIT: I found the solution. On the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` there is a line pointing the Document Root to `/var/www/html` so I modified to `/var/www` and now works great

Comment: Post the solution as answer. Don't change the title.

Answer (score 1):

The default document root is `/var/www/html`. Move `tests` to `/var/www/html/tests`.